# Online Estimation of a Joint Distribution from batches of data

Tags: joint-distribution, moving-average, density-estimation, online-algorithms

I want to implement an algorithm for the online estimation of a joint probability distribution from a sequence of mini batches sampled from the real distribution. The distribution is discrete and non parametric. I need to keep updated my estimation by embedding the information from the batches and gradually approximate the real distribution if possible.

What I was thinking about was a sort of EMA: $P(x,y)_{t+1} = \alpha \cdot P(x,y)_t + (1-\alpha) P(x,y)_{B}$ where $P(x,y)_{B}$ is estimated from the current sample batch.

Is it a good idea? I hope I was able to explain clearly my problem, in any case I remain available for further explanations.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (i.e. updating a posterior distribution based on a stream of observations) is called *filtering*. It is a well-studied problem for which several solutions exist. Here are a few reviews that might be helpful for you:

- Review on particle methods: Kantas, N., Doucet, A., Singh, S. S., Maciejowski, J., & Chopin, N. (2015). On particle methods for parameter estimation in state-space models.
- Review on non-linear filtering: Kutschireiter, A., Surace, S. C., & Pfister, J. P. (2020). The Hitchhiker’s guide to nonlinear filtering. Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 94, 102307.
- A recent paper showing a efficient implementation of particle filtering for experimental settings: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.07539.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I read something and I think my problem is a bit different (maybe). It is not that I have an hidden variable. I can fully determine the $P(x, y)$ at each step, given a batch of data. In need to keep my estimation updated based on the new samples. My samples are images labelled with segmentation masks, so that $P(X=i, Y=j) = \{ \text{probability that a pixel of value i is assigned to a label j} \}$. Given an image-label batch, I can compute a "local" $P(x,y)$ by iterating every pixel. But how can I online update the estimation of the overall distribution of the whole dataset?

Comment: If your estimate of the distribution can be easily computed at each time step, you probably don't need to combine your past and present estimations: you can simply compute a new estimate from all the data you have so far. Otherwise, different MCMC sampling techniques could be used, eg the Metropolis-Hastings algo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm

Comment: Ok, I see. So do you mean continuously accumulating the new data on the bins and then recompute the PDF by normalizing? May I have numeric/memory problems due to the large numbers to be handled? After a while every bin can have billions of entries. Is there an efficient way to do that?